# How to use Sphinx section links within a code block

Tags: restructuredtext

May be there are multiple posts on this extension not working. I am not getting where the issue is as I am new to RST.

I am trying to cross ref to a section from inside a code block. I have enabled the `'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel'` in the `conf.py` file. But I am not able to see the link in the generated HTML.

**conf.py**

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel'
]
```

**doc.rst**

```
.. code-block:: RST

    FTP_ENABLED: "sgsf"
    FTP_USERNAME: asdasd
    FTP_PASSWORD: asdasd
    FTP_HOSTNAME: asdasd
    FTP_PORT: 21
    FTP_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: Use the URL by :ref:`Section 1`

Section 1
---------

Section text here
```

Comment: You cannot do that. `code-block` is for code only, not for interpreted reStructuredText roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.. parsed-literal::` directive[1], but note that you can not specify language anymore.

[1] https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal